# Can't find what's wrong in onBindViewHolder in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter Class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm trying to display an image and three textViews in recyclerView using Firebase but all i'm getting is a blank page. I'm thinking there's something wrong with the onBindViewHolder method, but i can't seem to find what.

**onCreate**

```
    mFoodList=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.foodList);
    mFoodList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mFoodList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Item");
    mQuery=mDatabase.orderByKey();

    mOptions=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Food>().setQuery(mQuery, Food.class).build();
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener=new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()==null){
                Intent loginIntent=new Intent(MenuActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
            }
        }
    };
```

**onStart** - This is where i'm having problems.

```
    @Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    FBRA = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder>(mOptions) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull Food model) {
            viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
            viewHolder.setPrice(model.getPrice());
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getImage());
        }

        @Override
        public FoodViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.singlemenuitem, parent, false);

            return new FoodViewHolder(view);
        }

    };
    mFoodList.setAdapter(FBRA);
}
```

**FoodViewHolder**

```
    public static class FoodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mView;
    public FoodViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView=itemView;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        TextView food_name=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.foodName);
        food_name.setText(name);
    }

    public void setPrice(String price){
        TextView food_price=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.foodPrice);
        food_price.setText(price);
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc){
        TextView food_desc=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.foodDesc);
        food_desc.setText(desc);
    }

    public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){
        ImageView food_image=(ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.foodImage);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(food_image);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't help with your main question, but I wanted to mention that your ViewHolder isn't following best practices. You should perform all of your `findViewById()` calls in the constructor; doing them on-demand in the setters will seriously affect performance if the user scrolls your recyclerview quickly.

Comment: Could you check `getItemCount` inside FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and didn't return 0? Then check FirebaseRecyclerAdapter is listening data. The FirebaseRecyclerAdapter getItemCount  requires `mSnapshots.isListening`.

Comment: I don't know how to do that actually. I don't have a 'getItem' method. Is there any way i can add it here?

Comment: I'm having trouble with the `position` too.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using `FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder#setLifecycleOwner(this)`, you'll have to manually call `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter#[start/stop]Listening()`. I would recommend reading the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#firebaserecycleradapter-lifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

[As said by SUPERCILEX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48611688), you are using FirebaseRecyclerOption.Builder,
so you need to manually start and stop FirebaseRecyclerView listening.

So put Onstart()

```
mFoodList.startListening();
```

and OnStop()

```
mFoodList.stopListening();
```